# unit test get_absolute_url django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing

I'm pretty new to django, and writing tests. I'm currently working on a project that has two models, Project and Technologies. The project models has a many to many relationship with the technologies model.  I have a view that overrides the get_queryset method. On my coverage report this method is my only miss. I am looking for guidance on how to write a unit test for this method. Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

models.py

```
from django.db import models 
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify 
from django.urls import reverse 

class Technologies(models.Model): 

    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True) 
    slug = models.SlugField() 

    def __str__(self): 
        return self.slug 

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        self.slug = slugify(self.name) 
        super(Technologies, self).save(*args, **kwargs) 

class Project(models.Model): 

    title = models.CharField(max_length=64) 
    description = models.CharField(max_length=128) 
    repo = models.URLField() 
    slug = models.SlugField() 

    image = models.ImageField( 
            upload_to='project_images', 
            default='project_images/default_project.png') 
    technologies = models.ManyToManyField(Technologies) 

    def __str__(self): 
        return self.title 

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        self.slug = slugify(self.title) 
        super(Project, self).save(*args, **kwargs) 

    def get_absolute_url(self): 
        return reverse("projects:detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView, ListView 
from .models import Project 

class ProjectsListView(ListView): 

    model = Project 

class ProjectDetailView(DetailView): 

    model = Project 

class TechnologiesListView(ListView): 

    model = Project 
    allow_empty = False  # If list is empty 404 

    def get_queryset(self): 

        return Project.objects.filter(technologies__slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path 
from . import views 

   app_name = "projects" 
   urlpatterns = [ 

        path('', view=views.ProjectsListView.as_view(), name='list'), 
        path('<slug>', view=views.ProjectDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'), 
        path('tagged/<slug>', view=views.TechnologiesListView.as_view(), name='tech_list'), 

    ]
```

so my question is with this method:

```
def get_queryset(self): 

    return Project.objects.filter(technologies__slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
```

test_views.py

```
import pytest
from django.test import RequestFactory
from django.urls import reverse
from mixer.backend.django import mixer

from projects.views import ProjectDetailView, ProjectsListView, TechnologiesListView


@pytest.mark.django_db
class TestProjectViews:

    def test_projects_by_technologies_view(self):
        tech = mixer.blend('projects.Technologies')
        path = reverse('projects:tech_list', kwargs={'slug': tech.slug})
        request = RequestFactory().get(path)
        response = TechnologiesListView.as_view()(request)
        assert response.status_code == 200, 'Should be status code 200'
```

When I run this test I get:

```
    def get_queryset(self):
>       return Project.objects.filter(technologies__slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
E       KeyError: 'slug'
```

Is this because the kwargs are not in the request being generated from the request factory? Or is this a database issue? I'm pretty lost and confused on this one and would really appreciate any wise words.

Answer (score 2):

It amazing how writing out your question can break things down a little better. Here is my solution.

```py
def test_projects_by_technologies_view(self):
    self.tech = mixer.blend('projects.Technologies')
    self.proj = mixer.blend(Project, technologies=self.tech)
    self.path = reverse('projects:tech_list', kwargs={'slug': self.tech.slug})
    self.request = RequestFactory().get(self.path)
    self.response = TechnologiesListView.as_view()(self.request, slug=self.tech.slug)
    assert self.response.status_code == 200, 'Should be status code 200'
```